Cannot connect ALFA AWUS036NH (Ralink rt3070) with Kali Linux 2024.1?
I just bought ALFA AWUS036NH and Linux. It detected my adaptor when I ran "lsusb" command. But it does not connect to the adaptor. In the wifi menu the "available networks" option is disabled and with "nmcli" it say wlan0 disconnected. I am using virtual machine 2024.1. The adaptor comes with a CD.  I copied the driver in Linux, extracted it and ran the command "make" but got some error.
error:
 - ┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali/Desktop/2009_1110_RT3070_Linux_STA_v2.1.2.0]
   └─# make
 make -C tools make[1]: Entering directory
   '/home/kali/Desktop/2009_1110_RT3070_Linux_STA_v2.1.2.0/tools' gcc -g
   bin2h.c -o bin2h make[1]: Leaving directory
   '/home/kali/Desktop/2009_1110_RT3070_Linux_STA_v2.1.2.0/tools'
   /home/kali/Desktop/2009_1110_RT3070_Linux_STA_v2.1.2.0/tools/bin2h cp
   -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/kali/Desktop/2009_1110_RT3070_Linux_STA_v2.1.2.0/os/linux/Makefile
   make  -C  /lib/modules/6.8.11-amd64/build
   SUBDIRS=/home/kali/Desktop/2009_1110_RT3070_Linux_STA_v2.1.2.0/os/linux
   modules 
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/6.8.11-amd64/build: No such file or
   directory.  Stop. make: *** [Makefile:155: LINUX] Error 2


The driver you are trying to install seems very old.
Googling the directory name, the first hit was this Ubuntu forums post indicating the driver was too old for Ubuntu 13.04... back in year 2013. The directory name suggests the driver could be from year 2009.
You are trying to install it to Kali Linux, which uses a very new kernel. I don't think that will work even after installing the linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 package suggested by the other answer.
Since your USB WiFi adapter seems to use the Ralink RT3070 chipset, the rt2800usb kernel module that has been included in standard kernels for at least a decade should work for it. Your symptoms suggests a different issue.
Maybe you haven't installed the firmware-misc-nonfree package that provides the /lib/firmware/rt2870.bin firmware file (symlinked to /lib/firmware/rt3070.bin, as the same firmware is used for multiple Ralink chipsets)? If so, apt-get install firmware-misc-nonfree and rebooting should fix it.

Any time you get an error that /lib/modules/*/build doesn't exist, the problem is that the Linux kernel headers for that kernel version aren't installed. Given your exact error message and the fact that you're on Kali Linux, apt-get install linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 should get you what you need.
